# Expected primary error always occur in c

Tags: c

I'm using structure in c, my compiler is Dev c++ and this is my code. My compiler keep saying that there is an expected primary-expression before "struct" and an error expected ";" before struct. what should i do? any advice. thanks you guys

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <string.h>


    struct levels {      
       char numberone[20];
       char numbertwo[20];
       char numberthree[20];
       char numberfour[20]; };


     int main() {         
          int pili,sagot;
          struct record1 = {"Big Bang", "Super Junior", "BAP", "TeenTop"};
          struct record2 = {"Girls' Generation", "After School", "Sistar", "2ne1"};
          struct record3 = {"IU", "Lim Kim", "Juniel", "Eric Nam"};
          struct record4 = {"Park Shin Hye", "Han Ji Min", "Kim Soo Hyun", "Jung Il Woo"};
           printf("\t\t\t\tTHIS MENU IS ALL ABOUT KPOP\n"); 
           printf("\t\t\t\tChoose the    number you want\n"); printf("\t\t\t\t\t1. Boy Groups\n");                
           printf("\t\t\t\t\t2. Girl Groups\n"); printf("\t\t\t\t\t3. Solo Performer\n"); 
           printf("\t\t\t\t\t4. Actress/Actor\n"); scanf("%d",&pili);


         return 0; 
         getch(); }
```

Comment: Try replace `struct record1` with `struct levels record1`, and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing your struct name on your declarations :

```
struct levels record1 = {"Big Bang", "Super Junior", "BAP", "TeenTop"};
struct levels record2 = {"Girls' Generation", "After School", "Sistar", "2ne1"};
struct levels record3 = {"IU", "Lim Kim", "Juniel", "Eric Nam"};
struct levels record4 = {"Park Shin Hye", "Han Ji Min", "Kim Soo Hyun", "Jung Il Woo"};
```

However I'd also suggest you use a `typedef` :

```
typedef struct levels {      
   char numberone[20];
   char numbertwo[20];
   char numberthree[20];
   char numberfour[20]; } levels;
```

And then use declarations like this one :

```
levels record1 = {"Big Bang", "Super Junior", "BAP", "TeenTop"};
```

Comment: sorry I'm just a newbie here. thanks for answering my question :)

Answer (score 1):

The lines where you use the structs should not look like this:

```
struct record1 = {"Big Bang", "Super Junior", "BAP", "TeenTop"};
```

but like this:

```
struct levels record1 = {"Big Bang", "Super Junior", "BAP", "TeenTop"};
```